# Is it possible to return custom Java objects combining multiple aggregates in Spring Data JDBC?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I have multiple aggregate classes, such as Request, Scribe, Candidate, and Exam.

Sample schema:

Request (id, scribe_id, candidate_id, exam_id, status)

Scribe (id, name)

Candidate (id, name)

Exam (id, name, schedule)

As you can see, `Request` table has references to Scribe, Candidate, and Exam tables.
For one of the requirements, I need to return all requests based on a condition by including all the corresponding details of scribe, candidate, and exam.

For this, the query in my repository class will be similar to the following:

```
SELECT r.id, r.status, c.name, s.name,
                e.schedule, e.name
            FROM request r 
            JOIN candidate c ON r.candidate=c.id
            JOIN scribe s ON r.scribe=s.id
            JOIN exam e ON r.exam=e.id
            WHERE <some-condition>
```

Now, is there a way to map the result of this query directly to a custom Java object and return the same in Spring Data JDBC?
I believe another alternative is to use the Spring JDBC template.
Curious, any out-of-the-box support from Spring Data JDBC?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to return custom Java object by setting `rowMapperClass` value of `org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Query` annotation. For this need to define RowMapper for custom Java object.

Changes look similar to the following:

```
public class RequestResourceRowMapper implements RowMapper<RequestResource> {
    @Override
    public RequestResource mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNumber) throws SQLException { ... }
}
```

In repository class, need to set `rowMapper` value.

```
 @Query(value = """
              SELECT r.id, r.status, c.name, s.name,
                e.schedule, e.name
            FROM request r 
            JOIN candidate c ON r.candidate=c.id
            JOIN scribe s ON r.scribe=s.id
            JOIN exam e ON r.exam=e.id
            WHERE <some-condition>
            """,
            rowMapperClass = RequestResourceRowMapper.class)
    List<RequestResource> searchRequestResources(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

This could have even been possible without using a custom row mapper as well, but in that case, you will have to assign different names to the columns across the tables. You could have defined a simple class and defined all the fields in there and for mapping the java fields with the corresponding columns in the table, you could have used the @Column attributes example:

```
public class RequestData {

@Column("id")
private Integer requestId;

@Column("scribe_id")
private String scribeId;

@Column("candidate_id")
private Integer candidateId;

@Column("scribe_name")
private String scribeName;

@Column("candidate_name")
private String candidateName;

@Column("exam_name")
private String examName;

@Column("exam_schedule")
private String examSchedule;

}
```

However, for such case, you need to have different column names across the schema's which might not be possible in your case as you have same column names in multiple schemas.